# Django: How to get all perimssions from Permission Model (auth_permission)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to get list of all permissions from Permission Model.

I have tried following commands.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import *

Permission.objects.all()
```

When I tried to execute query command then it throws following error.

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

I have checked other models like Group, User are working correctly.

Comment: Where do you have your first snippet? In what file?

Comment: I have tried it both in Django views and Django console.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: I am using Django 1.7 and Python 3.4

Comment: it should work fine as above in `manage.py shell`

Comment: Yeah it should be, but not working now. I have not make any change..

Answer (score 0):

faced similar kinda problem few days back
try this :
change  installed django-registration module
<--old-->

```
 try:
        from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
        User = get_user_model()
    except ImportError:
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

<--new-->

```
from django.conf import settings
try:
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```